# Pycharm : not displaying files on the left

Tags: pycharm

I used to have my files on the pycharm box on the left of my window, like that : 
[image]
 but now Pycharm displays it under the list of directory :

[image]

I can't change of directory on the left part of the window : I have to use the horizontally-stacked list of folders, which is really annoying. Which switch in the conf of Pycharm do I have to check to have the normal behaviour back ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It was a corrupted project settings, I had to  close PyCharm and remove .idea folder in the project root to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try settings>Editor>File Types>ignore files and folders

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please try this in the toolbar : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html